# PyVISA GPIB functions will raise OSError until the library is manually loaded

Tags: pyvisa, gpib

I am trying to connect a new open source VNA, or Vector Network Analyzer, (LibreVNA) via USB to be able to automate some readings. I have run into a problem trying to connect to the device via PyVISA. I cannot get access to the SCPI commands as the PyVISA results in the error below and two 'ASRL/dev/ttyS0::INSTR' devices that are not the open source VNA.

When I run python3 -m visa info:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/visa.py:13: FutureWarning: The visa module provided by PyVISA is being deprecated. You can replace `import visa` by `import pyvisa as visa` to achieve the same effect.

The reason for the deprecation is the possible conflict with the visa package provided by the https://github.com/visa-sdk/visa-python which can result in hard to debug situations.
  warnings.warn(
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/gpib_ctypes/gpib/gpib.py:54: UserWarning: GPIB library not found. Please manually load it using _load_lib(filename). All GPIB functions will raise OSError until the library is manually loaded.
  warnings.warn(message)
Machine Details:
   Platform ID:    Linux-5.11.0-25-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.29
   Processor:      x86_64

Python:
   Implementation: CPython
   Executable:     /usr/bin/python3
   Version:        3.8.10
   Compiler:       GCC 9.4.0
   Bits:           64bit
   Build:          Jun  2 2021 10:49:15 (#default)
   Unicode:        UCS4

PyVISA Version: 1.11.3

Backends:
   ivi:
      Version: 1.11.3 (bundled with PyVISA)
      Binary library: Not found
   py:
      Version: 0.5.2
      ASRL INSTR: Available via PySerial (3.5)
      USB INSTR: Available via PyUSB (1.2.1). Backend: libusb1
      USB RAW: Available via PyUSB (1.2.1). Backend: libusb1
      TCPIP INSTR: Available 
      TCPIP SOCKET: Available
```

From my previous attempts I have tried to add the library of GPIB-ctypes and that's when the error is added. I get an error about not being able to find module named 'gpib' without adding the gpib-ctypes library.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [SCPI examples](https://github.com/jankae/LibreVNA/tree/master/Documentation/UserManual/SCPI_Examples) for this device you'll see that SCPI communications is actually done via a TCP port (19542 is the default). Furthermore, the GUI must be running and SCPI communications has to be enabled in the GUI. It seems that the GUI runs a small SCPI server. This is approach is commonly used with much more expensive USB Network Analyzers (e.g. Keysight and Textronix).

According to [PyVisa docs](https://pyvisa.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction/names.html), you should be able to use this syntax for the device string to connect:

```
TCPIP::localhost::19542::SOCKET
```

or

```
TCPIP::127.0.0.1::19542::SOCKET
```

I don't know if any of the VISA libraries will be able to discover this device via `rm.list_resources()`.